# What is the name of this medical item?

Tags: scar-tissue-scars, injury

The photo shows some kind of sheath, that's used in a hospital context in the UK, to reshape scar tissue and other outcomes of traumatic injury.

The product is made of two layers - an elasticated exterior material with a (fairly substantial/thick)  silicone internal layer.

I'm trying to find the generic name, and if possible specific UK brand names for this product. Help much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are describing gel tube toe/finger bandage which can be cut to size.  [Medipaq](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B003IDPXDK) and [Dykook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B071GH5M2R) are 2 brands I know of.

Comment: Perfect - and amazon links too, thank you!

Comment: Also a search for those suggests Pendimed, vivesole, are other similar products